# Angular 5 :Error trying to diff 'on'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: json, angular

So in my Angular 5 app I am iterating over an Array in a `<tr>` tag , the table is displayed. 
But as soon as I click the radio button inside the `<td>` , the error is printed in the console 'Error trying to diff 'on'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed'.

Below is my Code :

```
<tr *ngFor="let i of mpFASetupList" 
     [style.background-color]="checkFlag ? 'yellow' : 'white'">
        <td class="data" id="zero">
           <input id="faRadioBtn" 
           type="radio" name="anyName" 
           (click)="onSelectFaSetup(i)">
        </td>
</tr>
```

And this is my mpFASetupList Array :

```
[{"internalCode":0,
"authFlag":true,
"mainDashboardId":1061,
"validateStatusFlag":false,
"statusFlag":false}]
```

As you can see its an Array and not an Object.
I am not getting why its giving me the error even though there is no 'on' object in my code. 
Any Solutions ?

Comment: what is onSelectFaSetup function ?

Comment: @Arash That function changes a couple of flags to display and hide a buttons .
I tried running the code without the `(click)` event , still its giving me the same error.

Answer (score -1):

I tried a sample code snippet with your inputs and found working. Please find working code.

```
<table>
     <tr *ngFor="let i of mpFASetupList" 
        [style.background-color]="checkFlag ? 'yellow' : 'white'">
        <td class="data" id="zero">
           <input id="faRadioBtn" 
           type="radio" name="anyName" 
           (click)="onSelectFaSetup(i)">{{i.mainDashboardId}}
        </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qqvaga

Comment: I Appreciate your effort to answer, but unfortunately this didn't work.
As I mentioned earlier ,`mpFASetupList` is an array and not an object , I am expecting an answer as to what may be the reason that I am still getting the error mentioned in the Question.